# terraform kubectl provider not found

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to add kubectl provider for terraform module and I follow the docs from [Terraform kubectl](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs). I run `terraform init` and provider is installed with success but when I try to add a sample config, for ex: ( or thers from [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs/resources/kubectl_manifest) )

```
resource "kubectl_server_version" "current" {}
```

and run `terraform plan` I got the following msg:

```
Error: Could not load plugin
Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl" to
obtain schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl"
```

and when I tun `terraform init` ( with the resource in place in module k8s )

```
Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/kubectl: provider registry
registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl
```

some outputs:

```
$terraform plugins

├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 1.13.2
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl] 1.9.1
├── module.k8s
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl]
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes]



$terraform init

Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/kubernetes v1.13.2
- Using previously-installed gavinbunney/kubectl v1.9.1

$terraform -v

Terraform v0.13.4
  + provider registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl v1.9.1
  + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v1.13.2
  ....
```

some config files:

terraform.tf

```
terraform {

  required_version  = "0.13.4"

  backend "gcs" {
    ...
  }

  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
        source        = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
        version       = "1.13.2"
      }

    kubectl = {
      source          = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version         = "1.9.1"
    }
....
```

terraform successfully init the `gavinbunney/kubectl` provider but when I add `resource "kubectl_manifest" ...` in k8s.module terraform is trying to load `hashicorp/kubectl` provider

what i'm missing? :)

**Update**
with terraform 1.4.0

```
required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.18.1"
    }
  }

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.k8s.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.k8s.cluster_certificate_authority_data)

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.k8s.cluster_name]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "velero" {
  metadata {
    name = var.velero_ns
  }
}
```

Comment: You say it's installed with success but only show an error for trying to install it. Can you show the output when you think it has been installed successfully?

Comment: terraform init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/kubernetes v1.13.2
- Using previously-installed gavinbunney/kubectl v1.9.1

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `terraform` block definition with the `required_providers` as well please?

Comment: terraform successfully init the `gavinbunney/kubectl` but when I add `kubectl_manifest` resource in k8s.module terraform is trying to load `hashicorp/kubectl` provider

Comment: What version of terraform are you using? Whats the output from `terraform -v`?

Comment: @Liam updated 'some outputs:', thanks

Comment: Hello, I ran the tutorials you mentioned but I couldn't replicate the issue you are having (same terraform version and plugins). Could you provide the exact steps (and files) you followed to get to that point for reproduction purposes?

Comment: @DawidKruk thanks :) If you already have the setup can you try to add a module containing one resource from `hashicorp/kubernetes` for example `resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-first-namespace"
  }
}` and one module with a resource from `gavinbunney/kubectl`

Comment: because in my env, when I add the `kubectl_manifest` resource in main.tf works good and `gavinbunney/kubectl` is used as a provider but when I create a module (modules/k8s_templates) terraform is trying to find `hashicorp/kubectl`

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was due to referencing kubectl resources in a module, but the module needed the provider adding to `required_providers` within the module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "x.x.x"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem was that I had the `resource "kubectl_server_version" "current" {}` among with other resources from `hashicorp/kubernetes` resources in same module and terraform was trying to load `kubectl` from `hashicorp/kubectl`.

When I added `gavinbunney/kubectl`'s resources in main.tf all works good :)

Answer (score 2):

When I read the file `cat .terraform/plugins/selections.json`, I understand that the package is not really well installed.

In my project, I ran the following command:

```bash
cp -R .terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl .terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp
```

And after:

```bash
terraform init
```

This look to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you can look into **terraform state replace-provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubectl  gavinbunney/kubectl**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you leave only the kubernetes provider, the kubectl provider works just fine. Means, no need to declare kubernetes and kubectl providers.

Comment: hmmm ... I didn't try like that, I will try it :) thanks